# Update app with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5, app-store-connect

I seen similar question for earlier version Xcode, but advice not help me.

I need update ios app after fix issues for company of my client and had not publish first version app. Previous app publish another developer. I see many certification and provisioning profiles in developer.apple.com. I export certifications and profiles from account and built archive with parameters in Xcode: "Code signing Identify" IOS Distribution and Provisioning profile:* Ios Team Provisioning Profile.

Status on Itunes Connect is "waiting for upload".

When I try upload I see message: "the private key is not installed  on this mac".  What key is it?  Need I file with previous private key for update or I can create new? I try download certificates and generate .p12 file and create new provisioning profile, but all of this not helped me.

Maybe in Xcode 5 there are additional steps necessary?

Comment: not to undermine your question its called "certification" not "sertifications"

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the original developer transfer the app to your account. You'll then be able to get the proper certificates and provisioning profiles for it.

Comment: I have access to apple account with sertification and provisioning profiles, but not see key or way for create it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you have to generate the .p12 file from the keychain of your old developer machine or where it was generated. Because the certificate private key belonging to his system. Not yours.

Comment: I have access to client account on developer.apple.com and don't have old developer machine. May I create new key?